# Generating a QR code and an URL with php upon printing a receipt

Tags: php, url, qr-code

I'm building an app which contains a loyalty program for a restaurant. The program is based on scanning a QR code to get more points on your profile. The QR code gives points based on the amount spent at the restaurant.

I'm looking for a way to create a QR Code to print on the receipt, and then create a URL with all the receipt information in it (date, time, amount spent) so that both can be linked, and when the user scans it, I can retrieve the information on the URL. Everything is done on the app side, but can't find the way to generate the QR code and URL with php. Also, the URL needs to expire after 1 click (so it can't be scanned twice) and if possible, expires after 1 hour (so a waitress can't accumulate the receipt and scan them all at the end of her shift). Does anyone have an idea ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you are looking for a QR code library, although you can find many on Google, the question would belong to  http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . If you are looking for full-consulting, I don't know where to ask but unless you have a specific, reproducable programing-related question, it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these libraries:

- http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/.
- TCPDF: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classQRcode.html  (It generates pdf files whenre are printer friendly)